# How to use "extern struct" to share variables in c programming and compile with gcc?

Tags: c

I want some shared variables should be accessed among source files, *main.c* and *second.c* and  my header file is *all.h* defined the shared data type,

```
#ifndef ALL_H
#define ALL_H
struct foo {
    double v;
    int i;
};

struct bar {
    double x;
    double y;
};
#endif
```

*main.c* is given below

```
/* TEST*/
#include "all.h"
#include "second.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct foo fo; // should be accessed in second.c
    fo.v= 1.1;
    fo.i = 12;

    struct bar ba; // should be accessed in second.c
    ba.x= 2.1;
    ba.y= 2.2;

    sec(); // function defined in second.c

    return 0;
}
```

*second.h* is given below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "all.h"

int sec();
```

*second.c* is given below

```
#include "second.h"

extern struct foo fo;
extern struct bar ba;

int sec()
{
    printf("OK is %f\n", fo.v+ba.x);

    return 0;
}
```

I thought i have all the declaration and include the headers. But when i compile

```
    gcc -o main main.c second.c 

or 

    gcc -c second.c
    gcc -c main.c
    gcc -o main main.o second.o
```

It will give some error like

```
second.o: In function `sec':
second.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `fo'
second.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `ba'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think somewhere of the use of `extern` was wrong or i use the `gcc` incorrectly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the scope. Your variables (`fo` & `ba`)  have local scope as they are declared within `main`.So, their visibility is restricted to within `main` function. Please make them global variables and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that the linker is unable to find `fo` and `ba`.  With the `extern` declaration you have told the compiler that the variables will exist in some other translation unit, but they don't.

You need to move the `struct foo fo;` and `struct bar ba;` outside of the `main()` function.  Right now, they are function local variables.  They need to be global variables for this to work.

Comment: Only if you include `main.h` in **exactly one file**.  If you include it in two files, then you will have multiple implementations of each variable.  This will usually result in a linker error; when it goes to resolve the symbol `fo` it will find more than one candidate, and so linking will fail.

Answer (score 3):

main.h:

```
typedef struct
{
    double v;
    int i;
} Foo;
```

extern.h:

```
extern Foo fo; // "fo is a global variable stored somewhere else"
```

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "extern.h"
//use fo.v here
```

second.c:

```
#include "second.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "extern.h"
Foo fo; // "store the data of fo here"
//use fo.v here
```

Just include `#include "main.h"` and `#include "extern.h"` in all .c files you want to use `fo`.
Notice that `Foo fo` is only in second.c, nowhere else.